# Storing Huge Amount of Files in the Application Bundle

Tags: iphone, database, file

Um, I working on a dictionary app and currently trying to add narration for each article. I have about 97000 AAC-files. They are tiny - about 3-5 kilobytes each, but there are so many of them! I don't need SQL DB for access management because filenames are identical to the primary keys, so given the key I will be able to pick a proper sound file from disk and play it (I expect so).

The thing I worry about are issues related to huge number of files. I don't really want to mess up with CoreData.

Will there be any problems if I just add all these files to the application bundle? Will Xcode be angry at me? Will iOS be OK with that?

If not what should I use then? How to handle huge (~100'000) number of files properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction on the number of files that can be added to your application bundle.

It would be better for you if you can put the files on a folder(say audio) in the app bundle.